# Moving a part of an image with GIMP?

Tags: gimp, images, resize

This is the original image and I want to move the text to the right of the image:

[image]

But I failed, I tried to resize the canvas but then when I move the text the layer gets invisible when put on the resized canvas area:

[image]

I'm sure I'm just doing it wrong with GIMP and I wonder if you can help me to achieve the result?

Thanks

Comment: I can't seem to manage to move a selected part of the image at all no matter what I try...

Comment: Hi there and welcome - please do not use the answer field for questions. Use the comment field or start your own question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let me see. Guessing what you did there:

1. Image/Canvas Size: Set width to 300px. Leave height unchanged. Click Resize.
2. Select Region with Text. Cut (Ctrl-X)
3. Paste (Ctrl-V). Move to right. Text disappers

Right?

So, what happen. Any image in Gimp has at least one layer. You have resized the image, but not the layer. Your text is now a floating selection outside any layer and therefore invisible. Simple fix:

- Instead of Paste, use Edit/Paste As/New Layer. Here you go:
  [image]
- Alternatively, make sure there is at least one layer that covers the whole image.

Comment: You can also click the New Layer icon in the Layers dialog (the white page on the bottom left) after a normal paste (Ctrl-V).  This will transform the floating selection into a new layer.

Comment: You are correct. Thanks a lot for the help. I'm a newbie with GIMP and need to learn layers.

Answer (score 6):

1. Select
2. Press Ctrl+Alt
3. Grab inside selected area with the tool you used for selecting, drag
4. Press M to switch to Move tool to ajust position of the moved selection, if you need to
5. Ctrl+H to add the floating selection back to the layer.